# Search results differ in Linkedin API and site

Tags: java, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am using linkedinj java API. I search the key word android framework using the keyword search in API. It shows 110 results totally but when i search the same word in linkedin site it has 5616 results. I am confused why this difference occurs.

```
    BufferedReader kName = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String keyName = kName.readLine();

                searchParameters.put(SearchParameter.KEYWORDS, keyName);
People people =client.searchPeople(searchParameters);
```

Is any one can help to clarify?

Comment: do you have an authenticated user with the API call? How do you perform the search on the web - logged in or not?

Comment: I searched using my credentials

Comment: and is the api call authenticated?

Comment: yes it is authenticated only